# Trouble with VB CodeBehind of Label.Text

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having a very difficult time with something so simple.  I cannot get this code behind to work and I think I'm at the point where I've just been looking at it for too long.  All I am doing here is trying to populate the asp:label#Login_Message.text.

[image]

Intellisense is saying "Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30451 'Login_Message' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.    8   Active
" but it's not much to go on.  Any help is appreciated.

Also, why does my nav bar show two serviceapp applications when there's only one?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the label is correct in codebehind ...

```
 <asp:label id="Login_Message" runat="server" />
```

Then set the value to the label...

```
 Login_Message.Text = "something here"
```

Comment: I wish it were that easy.  I've checked it a thousand times lol.  You're code, copy\pasted still produces the same results.  What more information so I need to provide?

Comment: This [image](http://addohm.us/Images/Capture.png) should do the trick...

Comment: I've also tried it this way `Protected Sub Login_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Login_Button.Click

        Login_Message.Text = "I don't actually work right now, try again another time..."

    End Sub` --Produced a "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error BC30506 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types. ServiceApp 
" error

Comment: It seems strange.  Something to do with my project...  I remember now I had to manually create the vb file associated with my web page.  Now I am having to manually enter each object into the designer.vb file.  What could cause this?  Im sure it is an error on my end but where...

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that VS is not adding objects to my Default.aspx.designer.vb file.  Why would that happen?  This hasn't happened to me before.

By adding the following to my Default.aspx.designer.vb file...

```
Partial Public Class _Default
    Protected WithEvents Login_Button As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
    Protected WithEvents Login_Message As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label
End Class
```

This code worked...

```
Protected Sub Login_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Login_Button.Click
    Login_Message.Text = "I don't actually work right now, try again another time..."
End Sub
```